# Can I find out if a filtered iterator is empty?

Tags: rust

I have a filtered iterator like so:

```
let filt_it = a_vector.iter().filter(|x| condition_on_x);
```

Is there a way I can find out whether it's empty?

I need the iterator to **stay an iterator** for later use and it doesn't seem possible to clone filtered iterators.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can make your iterator [`peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable) and [`peek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html#method.peek) the first item; if it's `None`, then the iterator is empty. `peek` doesn't consume the item<sup>1</sup>, so the next call to [`next`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) will return it. However, `peekable` consumes the iterator, so you'll have to pass the `Peekable` around — but `Peekable` is also an `Iterator`, so if your code expects an `Iterator` or an `IntoIterator`, it'll work fine.

```
let filt_it = a_vector.iter().filter(|x| condition_on_x).peekable();
if filt_it.peek().is_some() {
    // The iterator is not empty, process it.
    process(filt_it);
}
```

---

Another option is to clone the iterator, call `next` once on the cloned iterator; again, if the result is `None`, then the iterator is empty. Then, you can process the original iterator, which will yield the first item again.

This option might not always work; not all iterators can be cloned. However, [`Filter` implements `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/struct.Filter.html#impl-Clone) when both the iterator and the predicate function are `Clone`. [Starting with Rust 1.26.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1260-2018-05-10), closures implement `Clone` when possible (before 1.26.0, closures would never implement `Clone`).

Also, this option is probably not viable if the iterator has a side effect, since the side effect may occur twice, or if the iterator is not deterministic, as both copies of the iterator may yield different results.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you call `peekable` with a [mutable reference to your iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref), you can actually keep the original iterator around after dropping the `Peekable`. However, if you had called `peek` before dropping the `Peekable`, you'll see that it actually consumed the first item in the original iterator. That's completely normal; `Iterator` itself doesn't provide an interface for peeking. `Peekable` will store the peeked-at item so it can return it in the following call to `next`, but if you drop the `Peekable`, then that stored item will also be dropped.